# How to efficiently join dimension tables, especially for streaming computing?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

For example, the two dimension tables are: streaming table A (id, date, time, col1, col2, ... col10) and dfs table B (id, ... value). 
I’d like to perform calculations for records in table A where id column matches the range of id in dimension table B when value>5.
What function can I use to achieve it in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have table A and table B

```py
n = 5000
tableB = table("no."+string(1..n) as `id, rand(1..10, n) as value)
rowA = 100000000
rowA = 100000000
tableA = table(rand("no."+string(1..n), rowA) as `id, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col1, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col2, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col3)
```

Use common join method for the dimension tables:

```py
select tableA.* from lj(tableA, tableB, `id) where tableB.value > 5
```

use dictionary method instead of join method. The result is the same as the above example.

```py
dict_B = dict(tableB.id, tableB.value)
select * from tableA where dict_B[tableA.id] > 5
```

The join methods of dimension tables can be replaced by dictionary, which not only improves performance but also makes the code more concise. It can also be used in the stream computing engine.

```py
// Simulated table A, table B
n = 5000
tableB = table("no."+string(1..n) as `id, rand(1..10, n) as value)
rowA = 1000000
streamtableA_temp = streamTable(rand("no."+string(1..n), rowA) as `id, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col1, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col2, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col3, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col4, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col5, rand(1..100000, rowA) as `col6)
share streamtableA_temp as streamtableA

// create a cross-sectional engine, filter table A for calculation 
// Here, dict_B[id] is passed in the filter parameter, which realizes filtering table A according to the records in table B
output = table(1:0, `code`v1`v2`v3`b_value, [STRING,INT, INT,DOUBLE,INT])
rse = createReactiveStateEngine(name="ReactiveStateEngine1", metrics =[<col1>, <col2-col3>, <(col4+col5)\col6>, <dict_B[id]>], dummyTable=streamtableA, outputTable=output, keyColumn=`id, filter= < dict_B[id]>5 >) 

// subscribe to table A
subscribeTable(tableName = "streamtableA", actionName="filterAndCalculate", offset=0, handler=append!{rse}, msgAsTable=true, reconnect=true)
```